# FileParser Util java method showing null pointer exception

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am writing a utility method for parsing csv files. For some reason, this method is showing a null pointer exception during insertion into a list of maps. I am not sure why. Can someone run your eyes on this and explain why this could be happening?  This is the point of the nullpointer exception:

```
record.put(header[i].toString(), nextLine[i].toString());
```

Here is the file to parse:

```
id;state;city;total_pop;avg_temp
1;Florida;Miami;120000;76
2;Michigan;Detroit;330000;54
3;New Jersey;Newark;190000;34
```

And the code:

```
public class FileParserUtil {


    public List<Map<String, String>> parseFile(String fileName, char seperator)
            throws IOException {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), seperator);
        Map<String, String> record = null;
        List<Map<String, String>> rows = null;

        // int colcnt = reader.readNext().length;
        String[] header = reader.readNext();
        String[] nextLine;

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i< nextLine.length; i++){

                System.out.println(header[0]);
                System.out.println(nextLine[0]);

                System.out.println(header[1]);
                System.out.println(nextLine[1]);

                System.out.println(nextLine.length);

                 record.put(header[i].toString(), nextLine[i].toString());

            }
            rows.add(record);
        }
        reader.close();
         return rows;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You variable `header[i]` probably does not have the same length of `nextLine[i]`, so you cannot use the same index `i` to retrieve its elements.

**Edit:**
I think you forgot to initialize `Map<String, String> record`. Is that it?

Comment: It does have the same length. I pasted the file contents above

Comment: You didn't initialize the Map. Why didn't you debug thru yourself, do you not know how to use the debugger?

Comment: would that cause a problem? it should be null to begin with. I'm inserting fresh data into it.

Comment: Wait, new to java. WhY does the map need to be initialized?? I'm intializing it to null..

Comment: Well, welcome to Java. In Java all objects must be initialized before you can use them. In your case, Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();